# Is the ZXing library thread safe?

Tags: java, zxing

I'm particularly interested in encoding rather than decoding, but I can't find anything definitive statements about the libraries general thread safety.

The use case is a server generating QR codes on the fly. I would like to know which objects, if any, it is safe to reuse across multiple threads.

Comment: I'm looking at you @sean-owen

Comment: If you are not sure about the Thread safety of the library, you can still  make thread-safe the way you are using/accessing it in your code...